# Leer HTML de un WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms, navegador-web

Tengo un Form con un WebBrowser, dos cajas de texto (1 y 2) y un botón. En la caja de texto 1 meto una URL, pulso el botón y ejecuto:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Uri myUri = new Uri(textBox1.Text);
    webBrowser1.Url = myUri;
    webBrowser1.Navigate(myUri);
}
```

El WebBrowser me muestra la página web. Hasta allí, correcto.

Quiero coger el HTML de la página y mostrarlo en el `TextBox2` y para eso hago:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender,
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
}
```

Pero no me muestra nada. ¿Podéis ayudarme?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentar con [OuterHtml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.outerhtml(v=vs.110).aspx) `webBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml;`

Comment: Hola Davlio. La propiedad `OuterHtml` no existe en un objeto `WebBrowser`. El enlace que pusistes aplica a otro objeto. La propiedad que usa OP es la correcta.

Comment: A ver, OuterHtml es una propiedad de la clase HtmlElement (Body), el Body es un HtmlElement. Document, propiedad de la clase WebBrowser, contiene una propiedad HtmlElement (Body) https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ah, ya veo. Debo ser ciego :) Gracias por aclararlo. Aunque te diré que la propiedad `DocumentText` sigue siendo la correcta en este caso. Usar `OuterHtml` desde `Body` te dará un HTML parcial. En este caso, el problema de OP no es la propiedad que está usando.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tal cual funciona bien. Lo probé. Tu problema debe ser la forma como has definido tu `textBox2`. Si no lo has configurado para aceptar varias líneas de texto, te dará la impresión que está vacío.

Cambia la propiedad `Multiline` del `textBox2` a `true`, y verás que todo funciona bien.